# Update multiple rows in SQL (phpMyAdmin)

Tags: sql

I'm trying to update a column called visit_date and where id should be propId, but it doesn't seem to be possible to do it this way in SQL phpMyAdmin.

There are total of 500 000 rows I need to edit, some listed below:

```
UPDATE `property_visit` SET (`propId`, `visit_date`) VALUES
(89, '22-01-2018'),
(89, '22-01-2018'),
(89, '22-01-2018'),
(89, '22-01-2018'),
(89, '22-01-2018'),
(89, '22-01-2018'),
(89, '22-01-2018'),
(89, '22-01-2018'),
(89, '22-01-2018'),
(89, '22-01-2018'),
(118, '22-01-2018'),
(118, '22-01-2018'),
(118, '22-01-2018'),
(118, '22-01-2018'),
(118, '22-01-2018'),
(118, '22-01-2018'),
(118, '22-01-2018'),
(118, '22-01-2018'),
(118, '22-01-2018'),
(118, '22-01-2018'),
(118, '22-01-2018'),
(118, '22-01-2018'),
(118, '22-01-2018'),
(109, '22-01-2018'),
(109, '22-01-2018'),
(109, '22-01-2018'),
(109, '22-01-2018'),
(109, '22-01-2018'),
(109, '22-01-2018'),
(109, '22-01-2018'),
(109, '22-01-2018'),
(109, '22-01-2018'),
(109, '22-01-2018'),
(109, '22-01-2018'),
(109, '22-01-2018'),
(109, '22-01-2018'),
(109, '22-01-2018'),
(109, '22-01-2018'),
(109, '22-01-2018'),
(109, '22-01-2018'),
(109, '22-01-2018'),
(109, '22-01-2018'),
(121, '22-01-2018');
```

Comment: Why duplicated id and date??

Comment: from your post it seems you mixed an insert statement with an update statement, it doesnt work that way, do you want to update a record that is in the database? if so then please clarify what field is the criteria based on and what would you like to be the outcome, if you want just to insert new rows of info then you just need to change update to insert into

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  And show some sample before and after results.  The code makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, I'm assuming you using MySQL Database. 
Something like instructions given [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)